# Magento: image file extension has %20 appended on to it when using WYSIWYG

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

when inserting images using the WYSIWYG in a page in the back-end, the image file extension has %20 appended on to it (which i believe is a space), if you click the hide editor button to view the HTML it will look like this

```
    <img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/example.png"}}%20" alt="" />
```

Clicking insert image from the html source view inserts the image fine, it's when i'm in the actual wysiwyg editor the problem occurs.

After I've selected my image and inserted it i'm taken back to the popup box with the "Image URL" field in the general tab. It's here that a space is getting added on to the end of the file.

```
    http://example.com/index.php/admin/cms_wysiwyg/directive/___directive/rfe33fSB1cmw9Ind5c2l3eWcvQ3wfwfer43cifX0,/key/rufheufuh4uh42eaf7611b26e2e1x1786/
```

Above is an example url from the image url field and a space is getting added after the last forward slash resulting in the %20, therefore not displaying my images.

Where can i trim this value as that will probably fix it?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I may be incorrect, but I seem to remember this as a browser bug. Try in a different browser and see if it works.

Comment: I've used different browsers and get the same result, i've also used completely different magento projects and not had this issue at all. So it must be this instance of magento.. The current store is simple, i haven't installed any modules or anything so don't know why this is happening

Comment: I've found a solution for now, i went in to the image.htm file in  js/tiny_mce/plugins/advimage and onclick of the insert button trimmed the value of the text field. I also used jQuery in a separate js file to slice the last 3 characters off of the string if they were equal to "%20" as the javascript trim function isnt supported in earlier browsers...still strange why this is happening though. I'll wait to see if anyone else knows why it's happening

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this:

```
 <img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/example.png"  _query="%20"}}" alt="" />
```

Or maybe:

```
     <img src="{{media url='wysiwyg/example.png'}}%20" alt="" />
```